# When a service both sends and receives a topic. The data doesn't go to MQ

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

```java
public interface EventStream {
    String STREAM = "event_stream";

    @Output(EventStream.STREAM)
    MessageChannel publisher();

    @Input(EventStream.STREAM)
    SubscribableChannel stream();
}
```

When I do this, it just goes local and doesn't send to MQ.

Answer (score 0):

The framework is not designed to do that.

In that scenario there will be two consumers on the channel - the output binding and the consumer; messages will alternately go to each.

Comment: Messages from the Stream framework are not sent directly to MQ but in this case they are digested internally and not sent to MQ